# analysis this datetime result and export just date in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

this is a function to convert date

```
 private function convertShamseToMiladi($request){
        $startdate = \Morilog\Jalali\CalendarUtils::convertNumbers($request, true);
        $sdate = \Morilog\Jalali\CalendarUtils::createDatetimeFromFormat('Y-m-d' , $startdate);
        return $sdate;
    }
```

when i use this function

```
$this->convertShamseToMiladi($request->startdate);
```

the result i see is same as this part:

```
DateTime @1577133000 {#273 ▼
  date: 2019-12-24 00:00:00.0 asia/tehran (+03:30)
}
```

and i need just this part : 2019-12-24

and i want to know when i dd() the date request why show me this kind of result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `convertShamseToMiladi()` method is returning [php `\DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php), so you can use `format` to get desired result:

```php
$this->convertShamseToMiladi($request->startdate)->format('Y-m-d');
```

Or if you want your method to always return formatted date you may change it like this:

```php
private function convertShamseToMiladi($request){
    $startdate = \Morilog\Jalali\CalendarUtils::convertNumbers($request, true);
    $sdate = \Morilog\Jalali\CalendarUtils::createDatetimeFromFormat('Y-m-d' , $startdate);
    return $sdate->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest You can use carbon https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ instead of morilog/jalali

You can change format of date in any other format using carbon

```
$date = '12-12-2017 23:23:34';
echo Carbon::parse($date)->format('Y/m/d');
```

> You can change the format as you want. https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting

Comment: I use morilog/jalali because of converting Jalali Date To Gregorian.

Comment: when you return $sdate try to format using Carbon::parse($sdate)->format('Y-m-d');

Comment: https://github.com/morilog/jalali#createcarbonfromformatformat-jalaitimestring